# How to save this data in cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, save, model-associations

I have a `User` Model and a `Boarder` Model, **Not every User is a Boarder but Every Boarder is a User.** 
**User model**

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    public $primaryKey = "user_id";
    public $hasMany = 'Boarder';
}
```

**Boarder model**

```
class Boarder extends AppModel
{
    public $belongsTo = 'User';
}
```

**add.ctp of my Boarders View**

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Boarder', array('role' => 'form', 'novalidate' => true)); 
echo $this->Form->input('user_name');
echo $this->Form->input('bdr_home_address');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

So during submit, add function in controller will now receive an array something like this

```
Array
(
    [Boarder] => Array
        (
            [user_name] => 'John',
            [bdr_home_address] => 'Some Street, Some City'
        )
)
```

`[user_name]` will be saved in Users Model while `[bdr_home_address]` will be saved in Boarders model. as indicated in my `$this->Form->create` the request will be directed to BoardersController, action add. **So how will I be able to save this?**

**BoardersController**

```
class BoardersController extends AppController
{
    public function add()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every `Boarder` is a `User`, the `Boarder` table should include a `user_id` field.

The `add.ctp` form can look like

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Boarder', array('role' => 'form', 'novalidate' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
echo $this->Form->input('Boarder.home_address');
echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

The `add` function from the controller is:

```
public function add()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        debug($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Boarder->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
            // saved
        } else {
            // not saved
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: and it worked like magic, is this in the Cake API book?. Thank you very much sir @cornelb

Comment: saveAssociated is in the api book http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: can I also do this in update? because Im having probems in update. my `id` field is not named as `id` its `user_id` so when I use `$this->User->id = $id` it wont work. how will do this that my id is named `user_id` so that I can use `$this->User->id` on update?

Comment: Im really having a problem in updating data, I dont saveAssociated can work with updating?